# How can I add below `if else if else` condition in the iterating data in my React-hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I add below `if else if else` condition in the iterating data in my React-hooks and split name and add name into individual div's ?  When I try to add normal if condition inside the iterating section, throws error.
`below is the condition like to implement`

```
if(nomineeteam == "QA" ) {
// add name for QA here 
}
else if (nomineeteam == "DEV" ){
// add name for DEV here 
}
else if (nomineeteam == "Support" ){
// add name for Support here 
}
```

below done so far :

```
const teamWise = [
  {
    "nomineename": "Name1",
    "nomineeteam": "QA",
  },
  {
    "nomineename": "Name2",
    "nomineeteam": "DEV",
  },
  {
    "nomineename": "Name3",
    "nomineeteam": "Support",
  },
  {
    "nomineename": "Name4",
    "nomineeteam": "QA",
  }
]



const [teamwiseNomination, setTeamwiseNomination] = useState([]);

useEffect(() =>{
  setTeamwiseNomination(teamWise);
})
    <div className="space_1 tile">
            <h3>Teamwise Nominations</h3>
           <div className="grid-container">
                {
                     teamwiseNomination.map(data =>(
                        <div key={data.id} className="team-1">
                            <h5 key={data.nomineeteam}>{data.nomineeteam}</h5>
                            <span key={data.nomineename} className="data-1">{data.nomineename}</span>
                        </div>
                     ))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map callback is just a normal function, you can apply any javascript you like for the most part. Give the map callback a function body (versus implicit return), add the if-else-if logic, and return the JSX you need.

```
{
  teamwiseNomination.map(data => {
    if (data.nomineeteam === "QA" ) {
      // add name for QA here 
    } else if (data.nomineeteam === "DEV" ) {
      // add name for DEV here 
    } else if (data.nomineeteam === "Support" ) {
      // add name for Support here 
    }

    return (
      <div key={data.id} className="team-1">
        <h5>{data.nomineeteam}</h5>
        <span className="data-1">{data.nomineename}</span>
      </div>
    );
  })
}
```

## Edit

It sounds a bit more like you want to *actually* group your data by the `nomineeteam` property. You can do this by reducing the `teamwiseNomination` state array into an object with the `nomineeteam` as a dynamic key and the `nomineename`s into an array value.

```
const teams = teamwiseNomination.reduce((teams, team) => {
  if (!teams[team.nomineeteam]) teams[team.nomineeteam] = [];
  teams[team.nomineeteam].push(team.nomineename);
  return teams;
}, {});
```

Then use `Object.entries(teams)` to get an array of `[nomineeteam, nomineename[]]` entires to map over. Render the `nomineeteam` into the `h5` and then map `nomineename[]` into `span`s.

```
<div className="grid-container">
  {Object.entries(teams).map(([team, names]) => (
    <div key={team} className="team-1">
      <h5>{team}</h5>
      {names.map((name) => (
        <span key={name} className="data-1">
          {name}
        </span>
      ))}
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-add-below-if-else-if-else-condition-in-the-iterating-data-in-my-reac]

Comment: That is really helpful, I didn't know that `return ()` code will do that trick ...

Comment: @soccerway Yup. You can also have individual returns for each `if` branch if you need to return different JSX depending on the condition.

Comment: I have tried but it is adding as separate div. ie I have two records for QA and 1 record for DEV.

Comment: @soccerway Based on the above comment and your shared image it seems more like you wanting to group your teams. I updated my answer with an example. It's similar to Ori's answer, but this is a common pattern. If this *isn't* what you are trying to do then I ask that you update your question to include your more recent code for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Group the items to a Map using the `nomineeteam` as the key, and then convert the Map to an array with `Array.from()`.

In your JSX map the external `groups` array, and then map the array of objects with the names, and render them.

To avoid recomputing the `groups` on each render use `useMemo` to memoize the computation. You don't need to add it to the state.

```js
const { useMemo } = React;

const createGroups = teamWise =>
  Array.from(
    teamWise.reduce((acc, o) => {
      if(!acc.has(o.nomineeteam)) acc.set(o.nomineeteam, []);

      acc.get(o.nomineeteam).push(o);

      return acc;
    }, new Map()),
    ([nomineeteam, values]) => ({ nomineeteam, values }) 
  )

const Demo = ({ teamWise }) => {
  const groups = useMemo(() => createGroups(teamWise), [teamWise]);

  return (
    <div className="space_1 tile">
      <h3>Teamwise Nominations</h3>
      <div className="grid-container">
        { groups.map(group =>(
        <div key={group.nomineeteam} className="team-1">
          <h5 key={group.nomineeteam}>{group.nomineeteam}</h5>
          {
            group.values.map(data => (
              <span key={data.nomineename} className="data-1">{data.nomineename}</span>
            ))
          }
        </div>
        )) }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


const teamWise = [{
    "nomineename": "Name1",
    "nomineeteam": "QA",
  },
  {
    "nomineename": "Name2",
    "nomineeteam": "DEV",
  },
  {
    "nomineename": "Name3",
    "nomineeteam": "Support",
  },
  {
    "nomineename": "Name4",
    "nomineeteam": "QA",
  }
]

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo teamWise={teamWise} />,
  root
);
```

```css
.team-1 {
  background: orange;
}

.data-1 + .data-1{
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```